# STYLE-WARNING: in SLIME 2.12 SBCL 1.2.7 Gnu Emacs 25

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, compiler-warnings, sbcl, slime

I get this message when starting SLIME:

```
; loading #P"d:/lisp/slime-2.12/swank-loader.lisp"
STYLE-WARNING: redefining EMACS-INSPECT (#<SB-PCL:SYSTEM-CLASS T>) in DEFMETHOD
```

The REPL works normal.

I am totally new to EMACS and SLIME and I'd like to know what does this mean and how to fix it.

I use Windows 8 (64-bit), GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32),  SLIME 2.12, and SBCL 1.2.7

Comment: This is a support request, not an actual coding question.  Please [contact the SLIME maintainers](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.lisp.slime.devel) or [open an issue](https://github.com/slime/slime/issues).

Answer (score 1):

I addressed folks in GitHub and [jackcarrozzo replied](https://github.com/slime/slime/issues/230#issuecomment-74561143)

with this post:

Good question - it took a bit of spelunking to find a full answer. The short answer is that emacs-inspect stores handlers for inspecting objects; when a particular object is inspected, the relevant generic function (based on type) will match and be evaluated. From http://lisp-book.org/contents/chslime.pdf page 16, you can run this to see the currently-attached generics:

M-. swank-backend:emacs-inspect

That pdf also describes creating your own inspector as well as additional features that look pretty cool.

Regarding your second point: lots of stuff gets printed to the slime-events buffer; unless you're having a slime-specific issue, you probably don't need to even have it open in a window. Warnings and so forth relevant to your code and interactions will come out either directly in the REPL, in the inferior-lisp buffer, or in one of a few other buffers that emacs/slime will auto-open for you when needed.

```
CL-USER> (use-package :elk)
; Evaluation aborted on #<SB-KERNEL:SIMPLE-PACKAGE-ERROR "The name ~S does not designate any package." {1002C9D683}>.
CL-USER> (defun moose (a) (+ a 7))
MOOSE
CL-USER> (defun moose (a) (+ a 8))
STYLE-WARNING: redefining COMMON-LISP-USER::MOOSE in DEFUN
MOOSE
CL-USER>
```

So, in summary: don't worry about it. Slime makes interfacing Common Lisp in emacs simple, and it does a great job of staying out of the way. Slime does admittedly have a ton of features but it doesn't force you to use them. Note to self: I should really get around to learning them some day...